# Select All items of a ListView (custom row with checkbox in it)

Tags: android, android-listview

**What I have:** I have a ListView with custom rows, having a CheckBox & two TextViews in each row. I have a button for "Select All".

**What i want:** I want that when I click the button, all the CheckBox in ListView get checked/unchecked.

**What is the problem:** In OnClick of the "Select All" button. i am doing this:

```
public void OnClickSelectAllButton(View view)
{
    ListView l = getListView();
    int count = l.getCount();
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) 
    {
       ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup)l.getChildAt(i);
       CheckBox check = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxID);
       check.setChecked(true); // true for select all and false for unselect all etc..
    }
}
```

Here **l.getChildAt(i)** is giving me the visible items only. And when the index goes out of visible items, the problem occurs. I want to check all the CheckBox in List, not just the visible ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Checkbox listview select all (disable/enable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553186/android-checkbox-listview-select-all-disable-enable)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It will occur, because ListView adapter reuses views. The way you are trying to do is incorrect. I don't think you ever should access listview rows through listview children.

Introduce a variable in your activity, that will hold the current state (`boolean checkAll`). When the user presses the button, it must set "checkAll" to true, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (for arrayadapter), or `requery()` (for cursoradapter) on your ListView's adapter. In adapter's `getView()` method introduce a check for this flag, so `if (checkAll) {check the check box}`

Answer (score 3):

have you looked this [Correct way to check all checkboxes in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876083/correct-way-to-check-all-checkboxes-in-listview)

```
int count = getListAdapter().getCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run this long-running task off the UI thread.
When you click button in OnClickListener:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                                final int position = i;
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        list.setItemChecked(pos, true);  
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

and in onCreate() :

```
this.mHandler = new Handler();
```

Each item in list view should be Checkable like CheckableRelativeLayout that implements Checkable interface.