# how to select all check boxes in RecyclerView by clicking Button?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This code in `onclick` of the Button in Activity:

```
if(v.getId()==recomendationSelectAllFriends.getId()){
    recomendationAdapter.selectAll(resultEntities.size());
}
```

This method in Adapter:

```
public void selectAll(int size){
   // what should be written here?
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876083/correct-way-to-check-all-checkboxes-in-listview   check this

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectAll(int size){
   // what should be written here?

   for(DataEntity e: data) { //your list of data in the array
      e.isChecked(true)
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

where e.isChecked field is bounded to the checkbox of the card.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean variable in your model class and name it checked, write getters and setters for that variable.

Now,
In your onBindViewHolder write

```
if(resultEntities.get(position).isChecked(){
    holder.yourCheckBoxName.setChecked(true);
    }else{
holder.yourCheckBoxName.setChecked(false);
}
```

In your function

```
public void selectAll(){

   for(ResultEntity e: resultEntities) { 
      e.setChecked(true)
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Model layer should not know about the view layer. In your approach you are ignoring this rule